# Wavelength distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I really need some help on this problem, as I seem to be extremely close to the answer, but am only differing in one spot. Here is the problem:

The function $u(f, T)$, where $$u(f, T)=\frac{8\pi hf^3}{c^3}\frac{1}{e^{hf/kT}-1}$$ is the distribution of blackbody radiation in terms of frequency $f$ and temperature $T$; $u(f, t)\, df$ is the energy contained in the frequency interval from $f$ to $f+df$. Use the relation between frequency and wavelength to find the function $\Upsilon(\lambda, T)$ that describes the distribution in wavelength; $\Upsilon(\lambda, T)\, d\lambda$ is the energy contained in a wavelength interval from $\lambda$ to $\lambda+d\lambda$.

I seem to almost get the right answer, as I get $$\Upsilon(\lambda, T)=\frac{8\pi hc}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{e^{h c/\lambda kT}-1}$$However, the book says the correct answer is
$$\Upsilon(\lambda, T)=\frac{8\pi hc}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{e^{\hbar c/\lambda kT}-1}$$ where $\hbar$ is in the exponent instead of $h$. I simply used the absolute value of the differential $$df=\frac{c}{\lambda^2}\, d\lambda$$ to substitute for $df$ in $u(f, t)\, df$. Can someone please help me on where the $\hbar$ may come from, and if my reasoning may be flawed?

Comment: It is quite common to replace the combination $h/\lambda$ with the product $\hbar k$, where the wavenumber $k=2\pi/\lambda$ is generally much more convenient than $\lambda$ for various reasons. As such, it's not unreasonable that the writer's habits would have led them into this typo.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo in the book.